# I'm trying make a Native code Plugging for my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, native

I'm trying to add Notix banner ads in my Flutter app. Notix launch banner only for Java not for Flutter so I'm trying to create my own Native Plugging to use Notix banner ads.

But my app saying `No implementation found for method loadBanner on channel notix_banner`

Flutter Plugging APP: `notix_banner_pluging.dart`

```
class NotixBanner {
     static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('notix_banner');

     static Future<void> loadBanner(int zoneId, int width, int maxHeight) async {
     await _channel.invokeMethod('loadBanner',
         {'zoneId': zoneId, 'width': width, 'maxHeight': maxHeight});
   }
 }
```

Then I set the channel in kotin file: `NotixBannerPlugin.kt`

```
class NotixBannerPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = MethodChannel(binding.binaryMessenger, "notix_banner")
        context = binding.applicationContext
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)

        binding.platformViewRegistry
            .registerViewFactory("notix_banner_view", NotixBannerFactory(binding.binaryMessenger))
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        when (call.method) {
            "loadBanner" -> {
                val zoneId = call.argument<Long>("zoneId")
                val width = call.argument<Int>("width")
                val maxHeight = call.argument<Int>("maxHeight")

                if (zoneId != null && width != null && maxHeight != null) {
                    loadBanner(zoneId, width, maxHeight)
                    result.success(null)
                } else {
                    result.error("INVALID_ARGUMENTS", "Invalid arguments", null)
                }
            }
            else -> {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalNotixApi::class)
    private fun loadBanner(zoneId: Long, width: Int, maxHeight: Int) {
        val banner = NotixBannerView(context)
        val bannerSize = BannerSize.Inline(width = width, maxHeight = maxHeight)
        val bannerRequest = BannerRequest(zoneId = zoneId, size = bannerSize)
        banner.load(bannerRequest)
    }

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(messenger: BinaryMessenger) {
        val channel = MethodChannel(messenger, "notix_banner")
        val instance = NotixBannerPlugin()
        channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            instance.onMethodCall(call, result)
        }
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        // Add any additional plugin registrations here
        NotixBannerPlugin.registerWith(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
    }
}
```

I set plugging is my: `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutter.plugins"
            android:value="com.notix_banner.notix_banner_plugin.NotixBannerPlugin" />
```

Please take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

After I installed flugin then I called it

```
await NotixBanner.loadBanner(6273334, 320, 250);
```

You can find more details about SDK here
https://docs.inappi.co/inapp-setup-doc.html#banner-setup

Comment: try flutter clean and build the app again

Comment: Already try but still not working